# unable to use git graph in vscode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, terraform, bitbucket

I recently got to know that we can squash the commit using a git graph from vscode. I installed git graph and tried to open my repo and surprisingly, I see a weird error which got popped up.
my repo : /Users/amman/orignal/base-config

````
The folder "/Users/amman/orignal/base-config is contained within the known repository "/Users/amman/orignal/base-config". Therefore it could not be added to Git Graph.```
````